# Slow loading Nuxt/Electron Desktop App with large datasets using rxdb

Tags: electron, nuxt.js, rxdb

When loading a page/table with more than 1000 results, it takes around six seconds for the data to load and sometimes temporarily freezes the application.

Pagination wont work because I need to get the counts for my "statistics cards" and rxdb doesn't provide any type of count functionality - so I'm forced to pull the entire dataset.

I'm currently using the mounted function to pull in the data and subscribe to updates

I would be grateful if any of you had any suggestions on how I could speed this up?

Comment: How many fields/field size for each record?

Comment: I'm collecting name, company, email, area code.

Comment: Does the data change often? I ask because one option might be to save the data as a json file, and include it on the page it’s required on with asyncData. The file will be compressed (brotli or gzip) across the wire, so should be in the ms rather than S transfer wise.

Comment: The individual documents never change, but new documents are being added quite often. I may give your idea a try, thanks for the suggestion.